# Unanswered questions that aren't

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I hereby submit a proof that 0=2.  It has to do with the following question which I saw in the Unanswered queue:

[Locus of centers of circles tangent to a given line and a given circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760696/locus-of-centers-of-circles-tangent-to-a-given-line-and-a-given-circle)

I went to answer it only to find two answers already present, thus 0=2.  As a corrollary, one of the answers was what I was going to answer, and better presented, causing me to upvote it.  So ended my glorious quest.

Why does this happen?  How do I work around it?  Is there something the asker should be doing?

Comment: It's because "answered" means "has an answer with positive score".

Comment: So when I upvoted an answer I actually solved my own problem?  :-S

Comment: Sort of. Give it a few minutes because of caching, but by upvoting the answer you removed the question from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: How do I work around?  Can I sort or filter the questions in some way to avoid such surprises, or am I stuck having to inspect the answer number on each question?

Comment: You can search `[geometry] is:q answers:0` to find questions tagged geometry with no answers. See also the [help centre page on searching](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching). That's somewhat inconvenient, though. So maybe indeed check the answer count. On the other hand, removing questions from the queue by upvoting deserving answers is also a good thing to do.

Comment: Could you convert that to an answer so I can accept/upvote it and remove the ? from the queue before somebody proves that 0=1?

Comment: I'm divided between answering and marking as duplicate. Also, $0 = 2 \implies \frac{1}{2}\cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 2$, qed.